# pass common data in every ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to pass rest=1 in every ajax call. How do i do that. Can i add it at a global level something like Transform Request

This is how my service looks like. I have several such service where only the endpoint or apipath changes

```
    return $resource(apiPath, {
        rest: 1,
    }, {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true,

            }
        }
    );
```

Also It would be good if i could only add to calls if the ajaxurl/apiurl is not in a exclude list

Comment: Google is your friend: [$http interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors), [Examples](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this in your main app config block.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                if (config.method === 'POST')
                    angular.extend(config.data, {rest: 1});
                return config;
            }
        };
    });
```